# Mercurial "pull" under different account on "target" server?

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, pull

I've got Mercurial installed on the live server so that I can easily "pull" in changes for deployment.

It was set up for my account, e.g. it always asks for my password whenever I do a pull.

However, now I want to hand over access to someone else. How do I "switch" it over to that other account, so it asks for their password instead?

It's a Ubuntu system.

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using http or ssh URLs?  Mercurial doesn't store the user name in normal usage, so I'd expect it to be asking both your username and your password in either case.  If you do have the username in a http or ssh URL you'll see it when you run `hg paths` and can edit it in the repository's `.hg/hgrc` file's `[paths]` section.